Why is there a significant difference between Clarity and GA4 data?
We have two to three times more users in Clarity than in GA4. Any idea why this might be happening? Thanks for your help!
is it because of different data models?
GA4 uses an event-based model, while Clarity relies on a hit-based model.
GA4’s event-based approach captures specific user interactions, whereas Clarity’s hit-based model records each page view as a separate hit.
